# Include mingw libraries in compiled file

Tags: gcc, cmake, mingw, static-linking, libgcc

I am using cmake to generate a Eclipse CDT MinGW Project. (Eclipse Version Kepler)

This is my Cmakelist:

```
project(IMGTODICOM)

find_package(ITK REQUIRED)

include(${ITK_USE_FILE})

add_executable(IMGTODICOM IMGTODICOM.cxx)

target_link_libraries(IMGTODICOM ITKReview ${ITK_LIBRARIES})
```

The code compile and run without problem in my computer, but in other PC it does not run. Some dll like `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` are required. I looked for this dll in my computer and I found it in `C:\MinGW\bin`. To solve the problem I copied the content of this folder in the other PC and the exe file finally run.
However, I am wondering if there is a better method to run the exe file in any windows pc adding these libraries in the compilation process.

I was reading and I should make that the compiler link to a static library. In Eclipse I tried to add the dll under properties>C/C++ Include Path and Symbols and under project Path>Libraries, but it does not work. I tried to modify the CmakeList but it also does not work.

I don't know why this problem and how can I include the content of `C:\MinGW\bin` in the exe file.

Many Thanks for any help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. For pure C code:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static")
```

For C++ code:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static")
```

Comment: Yes, vielen Dank. It works fine and your answer clear and helpful

Comment: Just tried the C++ variant of this.  Running the DLL through dependency walker, I still see dependencies on `LIBGCC_S_DW2-1.DLL` and `LIBSTDC++-6.DLL`.  Doesn't appear to be a catch-all solution

Comment: Which compiler and what artifact did you build?  Is it a DLL that you build or an executable?

Comment: the C++ options work for me, I do not see libwinpthread-1.dll, libstdc++-6.dll and libgcc_s_seh-1.dll anymore as dependencies.

Comment: The C++ option worked for me, thank you!